# Facing issue with Azure Function App after publish CompilationErrorException

Tags: azure-functions

We are using Azure blob trigger where we can able to process the files locally.

But after we publish the code in the Azure Portal, it started throwing the below error.

```
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CompilationErrorException

Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__20.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 326)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryExecuteAsync>d__15.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 94)
Inner exception Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CompilationErrorException handled at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw:
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.DotNetFunctionInvoker+<CreateFunctionTarget>d__27.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\DotNet\DotNetFunctionInvoker.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 321)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionLoader`1+<GetFunctionTargetAsync>d__6.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\FunctionLoader.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 55)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.DotNetFunctionInvoker+<GetFunctionTargetAsync>d__23.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\DotNet\DotNetFunctionInvoker.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 193)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.DotNetFunctionInvoker+<InvokeCore>d__26.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\DotNet\DotNetFunctionInvoker.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 265)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionInvokerBase+<Invoke>d__24.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\FunctionInvokerBase.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 82)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidTaskMethodInvoker`2+<InvokeAsync>d__2.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\VoidTaskMethodInvoker.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 20)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2+<InvokeAsync>d__10.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 52)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<InvokeWithTimeoutAsync>d__27.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 555)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithWatchersAsync>d__26.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 501)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__20.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 279)
```

Comment: Seems like dependencies problem, can you show the.proj file?

Comment: And can you show the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you set the correct `Runtime version` when deploying `azure blob trigger function` to `azure portal`:

[image]

If the `Runtime version` of your local `azure function` is inconsistent with the `Runtime version` of the `azure portal`, it may cause the problem you mentioned.

**Solution:**

You can delete the deployed function, then set the correct `Runtime version` and re-deploy the local function to `azure portal`.

The problem mentioned in this [article](https://www.koskila.net/sudden-function-compilation-error-for-an-azure-function/) is similar to the error message you gave, you can refer to it.

Comment: I have updated the runtime version to ~3. And it started failing with this error.
Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.DeleteIfExists(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.DeleteSnapshotsOption, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.AccessCondition, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobRequestOptions, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.OperationContext)'.

Comment: You can use [Azure Blob Storage client library v12](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet).